# Table visual with customized grid layout in Deneb (Vega-Lite)

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, vega, deneb

I am trying to implement a custom PowerBI reporting visual for my work. Basically I need a table visual that is able to achieve a custom grid layout and I thought I'd turn to Deneb since the native matrix visual cannot achieve it.

I need to be able to place a field, "Comments", underneath the other columns for each row header, "Projects", and have it span the entire row.

I know Vega-Lite is not really for table visuals but not sure where else to turn as we are using PowerBI. Really would like to get better with Vega-Lite for custom PowerBI visuals.

Here is what the original table looks like (with sample data)

[Table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej3vV.png)

And here's the output grid layout I want to achieve:

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AdVD.png)

The dataset is much larger and the Comments field in the data is very long, so that's why we need to wrap the field to its own row.

Here is what I have so far - just getting the projects on the Y-Axis which isn't much. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 800,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Project Name":"Project A", "Project Estimate": "12000000",  "Funded": "12000000","Budget":"12000000", "Comment":"This is some text"},
{"Project Name":"Project B", "Project Estimate": "9000000",  "Funded": "9000000","Budget":"9000000", "Comment":"This is some text"},
{"Project Name":"Project C", "Project Estimate": "6000000",  "Funded": "6000000","Budget":"6000000", "Comment":"This is some text"}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "text",
  "transform": [ 
    {"fold": ["Project Estimate","Budget","Funded","Comment"]
    }],
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "Project Name","title":null},
    "text": {"field": "value", "type": "nominal"},
    "x": {"field": "key", "type": "nominal", "axis":null},
    "yOffset": {"field": "Project Name"}
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample spec?

Comment: Hey, I've added images of the original table data, and then the desired output layout of that data. Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Yes, we need a spec to debug. How far have you got building this?

Comment: Sorry, i just added what I have so far. Edited original post.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this brings you closer to what you are looking for:
[link to a gist](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/db3a824af2ef0b6e6204d1a3ee56d6f4/TableAndVerticalConcat.json)

The idea behind my approach is to create stacks of "tables" using the facet view composition. Each view represents a Project.
Each stack contains two text marks combined by vconcat. Each text mark has its own filter transform, either to get rid of the comment row or to keep it

```
facet by 
"project name" [
vconcat[
{ text mark 1 },
{ text mark 2 }
]]
```

Comment: This is a great example of how flexible Vega lite is. I can’t name many other visualization libraries that can do this.

Comment: @APBReports I can't agree more, but I'm still wearing my vega/vega-lite infant shoes and to be honest vega/vega-lite are the only libraries that I'm currently using, due to the amazing Deneb custom visual, that brings these libraries to the Power BI table